# Using LogParser to calculate method execution duration

Tags: logparser

I have log-file like this:

```
30.09.2013  15:28:05    Start   MethodName  QueryGuid
***** Some logs ****
30.09.2013  15:58:32    Stop    MethodName  QueryGuid
```

I want to use LogParser to calculate method execution duration, but i have no idea how.
As far as i know LogParser do not support sub-queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer on http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/#comment-480

```
SELECT MethodName, QueryGuid, 
SUB(
MAX(TO_INT(TO_TIMESTAMP(Date, Time))),
MIN(TO_INT(TO_TIMESTAMP(Date, Time)))
) AS SecondsElapsed
FROM YourLogFile
GROUP BY MethodName, QueryGuid
```